# Eclipse feature: switch blocked sash in debug perspective

Tags: eclipse, ide

When I debug my apps in Eclipse I use 4 areas i.e: Debug-Console-Code-Variables:

[image]

I can move for free both vertical axes, but the orizontal is blocked and I con only move it for both areas:

[image]

There is some way to unblock the horizontal axe and block the vertical one?

**NOTE:** I've googled a lot to find this but I can't, I'm sure is because I call this zones, areas or panels but Eclipse documentation name them different...

Answer (score 1):

The separator is called a Sash or PartSash.

The way this perspective is designed the horizontal sash stretches across the full width of the page, so you can't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the *exact words*!!!! Actually this not the answer I expected :).... but, as far as there are other perspectives with vertical sash fixed, I cannot create my own?

Comment: You can drag individual views to different panes (or even a separate window) but I don't think there is a way to change the sashes.